# Class name to table name ambiguity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I had an already existing data base dump. I wanted to make a model for rails from that dump. I took a database schema dump and made a migration from it.
My table name in database is planet_osm_line and respective model is planet_osm_line.rb
Code inside the model is

```
    class PlanetOsmLine < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

Now playing around in rails console when I execute this query

```
PlanetOsmLine.where("name ilike '%salvi%'")
```

It searches in planet_osm_lines. How do I make it refer to planet_osm_line instead of planet_osm_lines. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `self.table_name` to assign custom table name

```
class PlanetOsmLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "planet_osm_line"
end
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks.